# Jquery Syntax error, unrecognized expression on id selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Im using angular and jquery to scroll to an element base on his location hash string.
In my situation i need to include in the string the '?' char, but its seems like jquery has problem with this.

This is the link:

```
<a href="#/faq#whenAreLotteryResultsUpdatedOnTheSite?">when Are Lottery Results Updated OnThe Site </a>
```

This is the jquery code:

```
var elem = '#' + $location.hash();
console.log($(elem));
```

The error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #whenAreLotteryResultsUpdatedOnTheSite?
```

Any solution?

Comment: Are you forgetting `$()` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, jQuery will refuse to select elements with special characters in CSS selector. You just need to escape them with `\\`:

```
var elem = $location.hash().replace(/\?/, '\\\\?');
```

This will properly escape `?` character.

<del>Also note that location.hash will already include leading `#` so you don't need to prepend one more.</del>

Comment: I tried your code and im getting this: #whenAreLotteryResultsUpdatedOnTheSite\\? and in angular function the hash does not include

Comment: Yes, this is what you need, you need to escape `?` with double `\` so jQuery could use it.

Comment: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #whenAreLotteryResultsUpdatedOnTheSite\\? when i do this   console.log($(elem))